DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL is called properly but START_ID IS NULL
I call DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL in different configuration and users. At my personel computer, it works well. below code assigns start_id to 1.
But at business computer, it can not assign START_ID. I mean START_ID is null. I think there is a missing Grant.
begin
--sys.dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task(task_name => 'TASK_TEST');
sys.dbms_parallel_execute.create_task(task_name => 'TASK_TEST');
sys.DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.CREATE_CHUNKS_BY_SQL('TASK_TEST','SELECT 1 column_1, 2 column_2 FROM sys.dual',false);
end;

select start_id from sys.dba_parallel_execute_chunks;
--NULL ( at business computer/environment ) --WRONG result.

select start_id from sys.dba_parallel_execute_chunks;
--1 (at my personel computer/ Virtual Machine ) --EXPECTED result is OK.

Expected value is 1. I run that code in different computer.
Which grant is missing ? Or where should I focus to eleminate the problem

ADM_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASK role and CREATE JOB system privilege ?

Can you check in dba_parallel_execute_tasks if your task is created at all? If yes, then try to grant CREATE JOB privelege to your user and then check again

are you sure the name of the task wasn't used before on your personel computer?

Thank you all for help. I wrote the answer to the post

I was running the above create_chunk query in business environment by using DIFFERENT SCHEMA(USER) because of missing grants on business.
I was checking start_id via sys.dba_parallel_execute_chunks. This view is masking "start_rowid, end_rowid, start_id, end_id" by using CASE WHEN USERENV('SCHEMAID')=c.taskowner THEN c.start_id ELSE NULL END. I don't know why Oracle masks these values.
So, when I check the source table ( sys.dbms_parallel_execute_chunks$)of sys.dba_parallel_execute_chunks view. I see the values.
Short answer : values are assigned and it can be seen from that main table sys.dbms_parallel_execute_chunks$
